# Why is the plural of 'leaf' spelled 'leaves'?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am a bit confused about why the plural of *leaf* is *leaves*. Can anyone explain why *leaves* is the plural form?

Comment: And yet the plural of Leaf is Leafs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a survival from the strong masculine declension in Old English:  e.g. knif, knifas (modern English *knife, knives*).   Intervocalic 'f' was voiced.  The modern letter -f- represents a voiceless labial-dental fricative whereas -v- represents a voiced labial-dental fricative.

Comment: Not just intervocalic, but also word end. 'boxez', 'iz', and 'uhv'. The question now is why is it still 'dwarfs' and 'roofs'.

Comment: I say *dwarves* and *rooves* and spell them that way too.  Not sure why some people devoice and spell with -f-.

Comment: @Mitch - I always use "rooves".

Comment: I *say* "rooves" but I *write* "roofs". I'd find it super weird if I encountered the word "rooves" spelled that way.

Comment: Tim, @HotLicks: me too! Why can't people be consistent in their rule-breaking?

Comment: @Mitch Tolkien thought it ought to be *dwarrows* or *dwerrows*

Comment: Garner, damn yer eyes! :)   https://books.google.com/books?id=mVcJqKs1isUC&pg=PA722&dq=%22rooves%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5-dQVY3uFbiPsQS924HoCg&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22rooves%22&f=false

Comment: @TimRomano I'm pretty sure you mean a labi**O**dental fricative. Or, rather, I hope you do! The other sounds a little bit painful :-)

Comment: @Araucaria: It's a Sicilian thing.

Comment: @TimRomano Yes, but 'f' represents the labiodental fricative, though. Not the Sicilian thing! ;)  (What I'm kinda saying's that there aint no such thing as a labial-dental consonant!!)

Comment: @Araucaria: Are you making a distinction between fricative and consonant?  Or quibbling over "labio" vs. "labial"?  I wrote labial-dental for the benefit of the OP, thinking it would be clearer. But seeing that I used the word "fricative", I might as well have restrained the urge to be understood by a non-specialist and used 100% jargon. Of course, the sounds I'm referring to are produced with the lower lip against the upper teeth, one of the sounds being voiceless (represented by modern letter -f-) and the other voiced (represented by modern letter -v-).